# How to plot y-axis to the opposite side?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this chart below:
[image: chart]

I would want the y-axis for the lower subplot to be plotted to the opposite side since that would make more sense. Is there a method for this? The `ax.invert_yaxis()` simply inverts the labels.

Note: For the curious, I simply used `.invert_xaxis()` to plot inverted bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, what you are looking for is

```py
ax[1].yaxis.set_ticks_position("right")
ax[1].yaxis.set_label_position("right")
```

of an axis object.

So with @meTchaikovsky's [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code, you'll get

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

x = np.linspace(1,10,10)
y0 = np.random.randint(0,30,size=10)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=1,figsize=(8,6))

ax[1].set_xlim(0,30)
ax[0].barh(x,y0,color='violet')
ax[0].set_ylabel("Y-Axis")

ax[1].set_xlim(30,0)
ax[1].barh(x,y0,color='deepskyblue')
ax[1].yaxis.set_ticks_position("right")
ax[1].yaxis.set_label_position("right")
ax[1].set_ylabel("Y-Axis")

plt.show()
```

[image]